# Error: ng:areq Bad Argument Argument 'blockGradeViewCtrl' is not a function, got undefined in Angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, codeigniter

I'm Using angularjs i created new js file and HTML file i called in HTML controller name is "blockGradeViewCtrl" and same that js also i run that it is showing issue like :

> Error: ng:areq
>   Bad Argument Argument 'blockGradeViewCtrl' is not a function, got undefined..

Pls some one help me.

**Note:any place i need to setting or not ?**

HTML code:

```
<div ng-controller="blockGradeViewCtrl" ng-init="init()">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Block Grades</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS file Name:ctrl.blockGradeView.js

```
alert('menu config');
hlApp.controller("blockGradeView", function($scope, $stateParams, gdiztunnel, growlService, $location, $timeout) {



    if(!$scope.gateMan(6)) {

        $location.url("/home");

    }
});
```

Comment: Please some one help the issue

Comment: i'm new of angularjs pls how to solve the issue